# Stray new line after user input

Tags: python, cs50

Whilst attempting CS50's PSET6, I was trying to create a double-half pyramid of a size specified by the user.

The pyramid is fine but there's a random new line after the user input and before the pyramid starts. How can I fix it? Any help is appreciated :D

The code is as follows

```
def main():
    hashHeight = height()
    create(hashHeight)
    
# get height
def height():
    h = int(input("Height: "))
    if h >= 1 and h <= 8:
        return h
    else:
        height()

#print hash
def create(x):
    for i in range(x + 1):
        print(" " * (x - i) + "#" * i + "  " + "#" * i)

main()
```

Comment: "How can I fix it?" - I'm afraid you can't: when you hit Enter to input the height, it automatically inputs a new line character (`"\n"`), which, unsurprisingly, produces a new line in the terminal. So it's supposed to work like this.

Comment: Thanks for the input! You're right, there's no workaround in that case but somehow managed to fix it without using functions at all which worked for passing the specific CS50 problem set I was working on

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    hashHeight = height()
    create(hashHeight)
    
# get height
def height():
    h = int(input("Height: "))
    if h >= 1 and h <= 8:
        return h
    else:
        height()

#print hash
def create(x):
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        print(" " * (x - i) + "#" * i + "  " + "#" * i)

main()
```